# POST or GET method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a service provider that allows us to connect to his payment page for payments, however the code he uses is php but we would like to do it in asp.net.

Problem is I don't really understand what the method should be, `POST` or `GET`, basically we need to redirect to the client with underlying parameters(not query strings) and then our current page that calls the request must be redirected to the client page with the parameters as well.

I do get the response witch is basically markup, but that's not what I want, I want it to redirect to the payment page, can someone please tell me what I do wrong.Thanks
Here is my code I use for the `POST` Method:

```
string query = string.Format("description={0}&amount={1}&merchantIdent={2}&email={3}&transaction={4}&merchantKey={5}",
                             description.ToString(), amount.ToString(), merchantIdent.ToString(), email.ToString(), id.ToString(), merchantKey.ToString());

// Create the request back
string url = "https://www.webcash.co.za/pay";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

req.Method = "POST";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = query.Length;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
stOut.Write(query);
stOut.Close();

// Do the request
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string response = stIn.ReadToEnd();
stIn.Close();
```

Comment: You might not be asking the right question here... when it comes time to submit the vars to your bank, you are stuck with one ASPNET form which posts back to itself... not sure, but am I correct in this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I totally understand your question, but as your title goes, here is the difference between POST and GET:
The GET method passes variables through the url. This can be practical or impractical (for instance if you plan to pass sensitive material to another page)
The POST method does not pass variables through the url, it passes the variables behind the scenes.
You'll need to decide which better fits your situation.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is correct you are saying, but is it possible to do it server-side?

Comment: @jinx Servers can choose to handle GET and POST requests the same, or they can choose to handle them differently.  Frequently PHP code will expect form submissions to use POST (you need to go out of your way to handle both) and won't process them otherwise, whereas ASP code usually handles them identically (you need to go out of your way to exclude one).  If GET isn't working then it's quite possible that their PHP code specifically expects a POST request for that page to do the desired action.

Answer (score 2):

Normally GETs are idempotent (meaning they don't change data). Use a GET if you want to be able to issue a request and not change anything. Use a POST if you're performing some sort of update/processing/etc.